# How to pronounce the word 'hostile'

Tags: pronunciation

There are two pronunciations  / 'hɒstaɪl ; ˋhɑstḷ / for hostile in my dictionary.

I'm wondering which one is more common or they are different in different areas.

Comment: @SovereignSun but hostile is adjective.

Comment: You beat me to that adjective comment, dan, but I'd still say SovereignSun is right that both pronunciations are common. I hear both. For all I know, I've even said both, although I think I usually use the second one.

Comment: @dan They are both common. There is also a difference when we mention either the adjective or the noun.

Comment: @SovereignSun The noun is hostility. :)

Comment: @joiedevivre It is a different noun.

Comment: @SovereignSun Oh, right, I forgot about the "if you encounter any hostiles" ellipsis type of usage. I pronounce it the same way I do the adjective, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both common pronunciations. **US** prefers [**ˈhɑs·təl**] as though it were written "**hostle**" whereas UK prefers [**ˈhɒs.taɪl**]